# How to retrieve button information in xml

Tags: android

I am new to android and I want to retrieve button information which is in the XML file. (specifically margin_top and margin_left). After that, i want to dynamically give another margins to that specific button in cording.  I can create new button with new margin but i cant retrieve current button margins..

Any help would be appreciated.

```
android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams lay = btn1.getLayoutParams();
```

this lay object hold all the information but i cant get margins from that.

i created my button using following code.

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativeTest);
        Button btn3 = new Button(TestActivity.this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(200, 200, 200, 200);
        layout.addView(btn3, params);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi [FlaMM3R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/738006/flamm3r)

My layout looks like below and you have to use same idea according to your layout.

**XML file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
        android:text="@string/hello"
        android:id="@+id/tv" />
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button android:id="@+id/btn"
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="100dip"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
            android:text="Button" />    
        <Button android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="100dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="148dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="62dp"
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout> 
</LinearLayout>
```

**Java file**

```
public class HelloActivity extends Activity {
    TextView tv;
    Button btn;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        tv =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
        btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);        
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) btn.getLayoutParams();       
        tv.setText("left : "+params.leftMargin+"\ntop : "+params.topMargin);
        params.setMargins(10, 50, 0, 0); // setting new margins for btn
    }
}
```

Use same idea in your code and let me know what happened. I hope it will be the answer you are looking.

Comment: Thanks Babu, i got the leftMargin. but the values are different. (not the same value in the xml)

Comment: <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="100dip"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
            android:text="Button" />

Comment: <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="100dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="148dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="62dp"
            android:text="Button" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

Comment: This Relative layout is in side a linear layout..... 
what i want is after getting the margins i want to multiply it with some ratio and set the margin again..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6991/discussion-between-yugandhar-babu-and-flamm3r)

Comment: yes now button position is changing, but before btn change xml margin_top is 36. but it shows as 54. that's is not correct right..I dnt know how this happen

Comment: no, i am getting correct values. left 40 and top 36 as in XML file for the given example. let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6991/discussion-between-yugandhar-babu-and-flamm3r)

Answer (score 1):

Give an ID to the button in XML file and use **findViewById** to get that button as you did for RelativeLayout. And then you can get all information about that button. You can modify the properties of button also. try it.

Comment: I tried that too. in the above code btn1 is the button object which retrieve by the findViewById and lay contain all the information about the button. the thing is i cant extract margin properties from that.. :(